# Статический маршрут в CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, маршрутизация

Каждый раз вручную приходится после перезагрузки добавлять маршрут

```
route add -net 10.0.0.0/8 gw 10.143.124.1
```

Пробовал `в /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1` добавить

```
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.143.124.1
```

Но никакого эффекта это не оказало.

Comment: а откуда берётся этот адрес 10.143.124.1? приведите, пожалуйста, вывод `$ ip a; ip r`.

Answer (score 2):

согласно [документации](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html), дополнительные маршруты могут быть указаны в файлах `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-интерфейс` в любом из двух форматов:

- в формате аргументов программы *ip*
- в формате `переменная=значение`

---

> Пробовал в `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1` добавить
>   `10.0.0.0/8 via 10.143.124.1`

вы явно попробовали добавить маршрут в формате аргументов программы *ip* (точнее, *ip* с параметрами *route add*: `ip route add`). в этом случае у вас ошибка — требуется ещё указывать интерфейс, чтобы команда в общем звучала как (1):

```
ip route add ip-адрес/маска via ip-шлюза dev интерфейс
```

интерфейс, как я понимаю, в вашем случае — eth1. следовательно строка должна быть такая:

```
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.143.124.1 dev eth1
```

---

(1) кстати, использование программы *ip* для управления параметрами сети — предпочтительнее морально и «физически» устаревших программ *ifconfig*, *route*, *arp*. рекомендую ознакомиться с написанной мною когда-то [«сагой»](http://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=129712)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте на сетевом интерфейсе прописать

```
up route add -net 10.0.0.0/8 gw 10.143.124.1
```

И данная команда будет выполняться когда интерфейс будет подниматься.

Comment: для дистрибутива centos это неподходящая рекомендация: её просто «некуда» применить. по поводу программы route; почитайте, пожалуйста, [эту «сагу»](http://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=129712).